# How to write an app that does not open a window in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to write an app that just manipulates the content of it's own tile and then silently terminates.
How do I get rid of any default window and splash screen?

Thanks!

Comment: For your own purposes I think you can try to play within OnLaunched method, eventually set black splashscreen. But surely such an app won't pass certification. You may think of setting a background task which will maniulate some things, but for this your app must be run at least once.

Comment: @Romasz `But surely such an app won't pass certification.` You'd be amazed at some of the apps that somehow pass certification.

Comment: @McGarnagle Nah, you are probably right. I've also seen some apps even using 'forbidden' APIs. I only hope that it's not so bad with this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this fully. Tapping the tile will always launch the app so there will always be a context switch even if it exits immediately.

The closest you can get is to write a Silverlight app and not include a [SplashScreenImage.jpg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769511(v=vs.105).aspx) file. When the app starts up immediately exit by calling [Application.Terminate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.application.terminate(v=vs.105).aspx) (Runtime apps always show their splash screens while loading, but splash screens are optional for Silverlight apps).

This isn't recommended and is likely to confuse your users. A better design would be to let the app launch and do something useful such as displaying more information about what is on the tile or letting the user know what changes are being made.

As Romasz says, this may not pass certification. See [Windows and Windows Phone Store Policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn764944.aspx) for the certification requirements. I suspect an immediate exit with no reason given will appear as and be treated as an app crash.

Comment: Thank you! So it is neither intended nor possible to create toggle tiles for certain system settings?

Comment: Correct. Toggle tiles aren't part of the system design